# GD imagenes con esquinas redondas php

Tags: php, imagen, php8

estoy intentando crear una imagen PNG con la librería GD de PHP y la logro crear y se me guarda sin problema,  el problema viene en que necesito que al momento de subirla al servidor se vaya con las esquinas redondas y no cuadradas, necesitaría colocarle transparencia a los bordes de las esquinas pero no consigo forma de hacerlo o  por lo menos eso es lo que creó que se tendría que hacer, si alguien lo a echo y me podría dar una mano les agradezco.

```
$im = "https://aqui.com/aca/imagenes_aplicacion/1024x1024_logo_app.png";




$image = imagecreatefrompng ( $im );
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor ( 512, 512 ); // new wigth and height
imagealphablending($new_image , false);
imagesavealpha($new_image , true);
imagecopyresampled ( $new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 512, 512, imagesx ( $image ), imagesy ( $image ) );
$image = $new_image;

// saving
imagealphablending($image , false);
imagesavealpha($image , true);
imagepng($image, "../$Pag_web/imagenes_aplicacion/512x512_logo_app.png");
```

por acá les dejo el código de todas formas

Comment: Si vas a mostrar la imagen en html podrías redondear los bordes con [css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius).

Comment: no la voy a mostrar en html amigo, por eso es q la necesito modificar antes de subirla al servidor